# Solidity - Filling and using array of array

Tags: solidity

I have a contract with the following data structures:

```
struct Answer
{
    bytes32 name;   // short name (up to 32 bytes)
    uint voteCount; // number of accumulated votes
}

struct Question
{
    bytes32 name; // short name (up to 32 bytes);
    Answer[] answers;
}

Question[] public questions;
```

How can I fill the arrays?

The following lines are not functional:

```
function addQuestion(bytes32 _name, bytes32[] _answers) onlyOwner { // perhabs it should be possible that others as the owner can add
  Answer[] memory answersLocal = new Answer[](_answers.length);

  //Question memory question = Question(_name);
  for (uint i = 0; i < _answers.length; i++) {
    answersLocal[i] = Answer({
        name: _answers[i],
        voteCount: 0
      });
    }

    questions.push(Question({
      name: _name,
      answers: answersLocal
      }));

  }
```

I get here the error:

> Copying of type struct Roadshow.Answer memory[] memory to storage not yet supported.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to access contract via web3 or something bridge like this.

the bridge still not support array of arrays, but solidity supports!

i guess if the error was in solidity you will see a different type of error.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use `push()` method instead of Solidity assigning.